# Stack overflow despite tail call position but only in 64-bit

Tags: f#, 64-bit, stack-overflow, 32-bit, tail-recursion

Originated from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722526/), I have this little F# code ([github](https://github.com/T-Becker/fsharp-stackoverflow-investigation/tree/real-so-source-found)) to generate random values according to a normal distribution:

```
// val nextSingle : (unit -> float32)
let nextSingle =
    let r = System.Random()
    r.NextDouble >> float32

// val gauss : (float32 -> float32 -> seq<float32>)
let gauss mean stdDev =
    let rec gauss ready = seq {
        match ready with
        | Some spare ->
            yield spare * stdDev + mean
            yield! gauss None
        | _ ->
            let rec loop () =
                let u = nextSingle() * 2.f - 1.f
                let v = nextSingle() * 2.f - 1.f
                let s = pown u 2 + pown v 2
                if s >= 1.f || s = 0.f then loop() else
                u, v, s
            let u, v, s = loop()
            let mul = (*)(sqrt(-2.f * log s / s))
            yield mul u * stdDev + mean
            yield! mul v |> Some |> gauss
    }
    gauss None
```

To me it seems that this should only call itself in tail call position, ergo never cause a `StackOverflowException` when TCO is enabled. But it *does* when running **64-bit**. It *does not* when running **32-bit** (i.e. “Prefer 32-bit” checkbox in project settings).

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.2 and F# 4.4.0.0.

Can somebody explain what is causing the problem?

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: I found these articles talking about tail call optimization [using .NET 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions/) vs [using .NET 4.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrcodegeneration/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4/), maybe they can help.

Comment: Also what version of F# are you using? I use F#4 and when debugging I don't see stack growing at all. I disassembled the IL code and it looks like the code F#4 generate shouldn't stackoverflow.

Comment: Please include a full repro.  What does the calling code look like?  "Tail recursion" in a sequence expression can be confusing, because the sequence does not actually advance itself, some other code does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the compiler's sequence expression compilation mechanism.  Here's a simplified repro:

```
let rec loop r = seq {
    if r > 0 then
        let rec unused() = unused()
        yield r
        yield! loop r
}

printfn "%i" (Seq.nth 10000000 (loop 1))
```

Obviously the presence of the unused recursive definition shouldn't affect whether this generates a stack overflow, but it does.

Comment: I've filed this as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/996).

Comment: Was it intuitive or unintuitive reasoning that lead to the problem? I am interested to know if it was just basic problem solving using `IL` inspection combined with factoring down to the minimal which I can do using VS community edition, or did you make use of something more? I am trying to improve my ability to resolve TCO problems. If you want this as a separate SO question I will be happy make it such. Also which version of the code did you start from, the GitHub full, GitHub minimal, or the example in the question, as I want to figure it out independently.

Comment: @GuyCoder - My reasoning was something like this: Talking about "tail calls" when looking at a computation expression can be misleading - there really isn't such a thing (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6615060/82959 for one related discussion, though not related to _sequence_ expressions).  So something like `gauss` will not itself ever overflow the stack, only the code calling it could make it overflow.

Comment: @GuyCoder - But once I saw that the calling code was just something like `Seq.nth`, that meant that there was almost certainly a compiler bug, because the pattern of "tail `yield!`ing" in a sequence expression is supposed to get optimized (not sure if this is part of the spec, but I think it's fairly well known).  So then it was just a case of seeing what parts of the initial repro were necessary.  Replacing `loop` in the original code with a non-recursive definition made the repro stop failing, as did removing the pattern match.

Comment: @GuyCoder - I didn't find looking at the IL helpful (there's so much compiler-generated machinery involved in the compilation of sequence expressions), I just tried minimizing the repro at the source level and empirically testing the behavior.

Comment: Thanks. If I make this a separate SO question can you post this as the answer. I think it worth sharing as comments do not show up in searches.

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to.

Comment: I posted the question as [What reasoning lead to the answer for `Sequence expression containing recursive definition is compiled incorrectly`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799031/what-reasoning-lead-to-the-answer-for-sequence-expression-containing-recursive) but feel free to edit the title, question and tags, I view it all as CC.