# What reasoning lead to `Sequence expression containing recursive definition is compiled incorrectly`

Tags: f#, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

The question [Stack overflow despite tail call position but only in 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35751350/1243762) lead to uncovering a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/996) in the F# compiler.

After reading the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35776618/1243762) I am curious as to the reasoning that lead to finding the bug as I would like to better improve my skills at resolving problems and understanding TCO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My reasoning was something like this:

Talking about "tail calls" when looking at a computation expression can be misleading - in general there really isn't such a thing (see e.g. [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6615060/82959) for one related discussion, though not related to *sequence* expressions).

So calling `gauss` will not itself ever overflow the stack, only the code iterating through it could make it overflow.  But once I saw that the calling code was just something like `Seq.nth`, that meant that there was almost certainly a compiler bug, because the pattern of "tail `yield!`ing" in a sequence expression is supposed to get optimized (not sure if this is part of the spec, but I think it's fairly well known). So then it was just a case of seeing what parts of the initial repro were necessary.

Replacing loop in the original code with a non-recursive definition made the repro stop failing, as did removing the pattern match. I didn't find looking at the IL helpful (there's so much compiler-generated machinery involved in the compilation of sequence expressions), I just tried minimizing the repro at the source level and empirically testing the behavior.